# Android : How to add Oauth1 header in Volley Request

Tags: android, android-studio, oauth, android-volley, android-networking

I am trying to use volley with oauth1 inside my project. but I don't know how to implement/use fileds like "Consumer Secret", "Token Secret" signature and "Nounce" inside the header like the picture shown below.

[image: Details needed to include in the header]

> Current code for json Request

```
     RequestQueue queue = VolleyUtils.getRequestQueue();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = ESRequest.jsonObject;

            ESJsonRequest myReq = new ESJsonRequest(
                    ESRequest.method,
                    ESRequest.mReqUrl,
                    jsonObject,
                    createReqSuccessListener(ESRequest),
                    createReqErrorListener(ESRequest)) {

                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
                    String ts = tsLong.toString();

//                    try {
//                        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
//
//                    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex){
//                        ex.printStackTrace();
//                    }
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                 params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                 params.put("oauth_consumer_key","4e77abaec9b6fcda9b11e89a9744c2e1");
                                 params.put("oauth_token","2da943934104293b167fe2feaffca9a1");
                                 params.put("oauth_signature_method","HMAC-SHA1");
                                 params.put("oauth_timestamp",ts);
                                 params.put("oauth_version","1.0");


                    // params.put("Consumer Secret","94efe40eb55a8d6f1d9d88696de0d37f");
                                // params.put("Token Secret","b89be3cfb341f87bfd7fdf7c06f3c4e0");
                                 return params;
                }
            };

            myReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 4,
                    BABTAIN_MAX_RETRIES,
                    BABTAIN_BACKOFF_MULT));
                              myReq.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                             //myReq.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                                 queue.add(myReq);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> Problem

I google a lot and build this code. but it's not completed. Don't know how to add the filed "Nonce" , "Consumer Secret", "Token Secret" into this code.

is this the right way to do so? if it's not how to implement oauth1 header with above details..

? How to get a header like PostMan generated below using these details with volley

OAuth oauth_consumer_key="4e77abaec9b6fcda9b11e89a9744c2e1",oauth_token="2da943934104293b167f6klfeaffca9a1",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1480672395",oauth_nonce="5KEfWK",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="nnbiava6yCkbSo1RDmtN%FmIoN4c%3D"

please help.. Thank you

> Edit

PostMan Response with Header

[image]

Comment: For headers, you should use `getHeaders` instead of `getParams`

Comment: Thanks bro... now i got    "code": 401,  "message": "oauth_problem=signature_invalid" . error. No idea how to generate signature with Consumer Secret and Token Secret.. can you  please help me to resolve it..

Comment: Post your postman screenshot with "Header" tab actived

Comment: I think inside `getHeaders`, you will use `.put("Authorization","OAuth oauth_consumer_key=..."`, not `.put("oauth_consumer_key","..."`, `.put("oauth_token","..."`

Comment: Postman screenshot is added and updtaed the question..

Comment: still failed to create signatue.. is there any library?

Comment: @AdarshAshok do you know a solution for this issue?

Comment: Were you able to sort it out? What was the solution?